# Are two cups of nescafe a day good for my health?

Tags: heart, coffee

I drink 2 cups of Nescafe every day.

8 a.m. first cup and 12 p.m. another cup.

I drink this kind of Nescafe and add with a spoon of condensed milk, not the 3 in 1.

[image]

Is this habit good for my health (especially my hearth)?